# How to add hours and minutes to ajax request sent from p:calendar primefaces widget?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use `p:calendar` widget with hours and minutes selector from primefaces framework.

```
<p:calendar id="dateSel" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" converter="ruDateConv"
showOtherMonths="true" selectOtherMonths="true"
mode="inline" locale="ru" value="#{model.date}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{model.onDateSelect}"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Hours and minutes selectors showing ok, but there is no hours and minutes parameter in ajax request (I'am using wireshark to monitor raw tcp). Only date sent. Thus, I cannot get the hours and minutes on the server side.

My converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value="ruDateConv")
public class RuDateConverter implements Converter {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuDateConverter.class);

    private SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm");


    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {
        logger.debug("Try to convert {}", string); //there is no hours and minutes in log
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = df.parse(string);
            return d;
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            logger.error("Can't convert "+string, ex);
            throw new ConverterException("Can't convert "+string);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
        logger.debug("Convert {}", o);
        return df.format((Date)o);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd say the problem is in your converter

Comment: You're right, looks fine. For me it works using public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent e), converter="#{ruDateConv}" and remove mode="inline". Can't get it to work in inline mode, it wont send ajax. Using PF 4